# "[ERROR] Sorry! The --v1 and --v2 flags have been removed."

Tags: s3cmd

Having this error and have not been able to resolve it after so many trials
i have reinstalled the ionic cordova but still get this error when i want to use angular 2 (ionic start boxapp tabs --v2) [ERROR] Sorry! The --v1 and --v2 flags have been removed.
but it works when i use --v but not --v2

Answer (score 1):

On the console (cmd):

1. `npm install -g cordova ionic`
2. `ionic start myApp tabs`

For v1 projects, use the *--type ionic1* flag:

```
ionic start myApp tabs --type ionic1
```

Comment: pls i want to run v2 project...this is my problem...by default it runs on v1

Comment: try this.  npm install -g ionic@beta

Answer (score 1):

I used this command:

```
ionic start MyProject blank ionic2
```

It worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
    ionic start myapp blank --type ionic-angular

Answer (score 0):

ionic start {project name} {template type} --type {ionic1/ionic-angular} e.g

```
ionic start todo blank --type ionic-angular
```

above command will create ionic 2 project for you and you can verify the same while CLI is creating the project

```
D:\Projects>ionic start sidemenunavigation blank --type=ionic-angular
√ Creating directory .\sidemenunavigation - done!
[INFO] Fetching app base
       (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.tar.gz)
√ Downloading - done!
[INFO] Fetching starter template blank
       (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-blank/archive/master.tar.gz
)
√ Downloading - done!
√ Updating package.json with app details - done!
```

Answer (score -2):

On the version 3.19.1 I used

> ionic myDemo blank ionic2

On different versions i havent idea
Try is easy!